# asn.1 DER Encode IMPLICIT SEQUENCE

Tags: asn.1, der

I am trying to encode the below ASN.1 grammar in DER format.

```
BuiltInStandardAttributes ::= SEQUENCE {
    organizational-unit-names [6] IMPLICIT OrganizationalUnitNames OPTIONAL 
    } 
    
OrganizationalUnitNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..ub-organizational-units)
                             OF OrganizationalUnitName

OrganizationalUnitName ::= PrintableString (SIZE
                    (1..ub-organizational-unit-name-length))
```

In the sample data, I have 2 `PrintableString`s "be" and "pai"

I tried the encoding as

```
SEQUENCE (1 elem)
  [6] (2 elem)
    PrintableString be
    PrintableString pai

30 0B A6 09 13 02 62 65 13 03 70 61 69
```

Is this correct? Here, how do I specify the inner `SEQUENCE` is `IMPLICIT`?

Comment: Yes, this encoding is correct. Your `OrganizationalUnitNames` is properly encoded as `IMPLICIT`.

Comment: @Crypt32, I wonder what is the difference if the `IMPLICIT` is not specified? For eg `organizational-unit-names [6] OrganizationalUnitNames OPTIONAL`

Comment: It depends on an ASN.1 module header:  `DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS`, `DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS` or `DEFINITIONS EXPLICIT TAGS`. In first two cases it will be implicitly tagged.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your encoding **against your schema** at https://asn1.io/PKI-Inspector.

For example, if

> the inline IMPLICT is not specified

but your schema specifies the AUTOMATIC TAGS in the module definition, your encoding will [match the schema](https://asn1.io/PKI-inspector/default.aspx?databin=H4sIAAAAAAAEADPgXsYpzJSUKsxckJgJAHhHtiYNAAAA&schema=H4sIAAAAAAAEAHWPMQvCMBBG90D%2Bw412aKEKDgWHtI0S0KSSdFEcUlokUCPU66L43611KthvfQ%2FenWkeCDnfCimMUFIDK406MCMyMGynIUk2kPKdkJSkvWtReI3W17arGWLnqh6bxyhpfiy5zDi8KIFh9%2B5qvXtadHdv27D3DkNvb4N9Xl9ATWg5QDkyVXyvYHt4AyWUzGmToBYnDos4iuLlKoBf%2Ff%2FUdiY83xpTRec82qpt9PCyv8Jikgwo4TL%2FAL2xo5BJAQAA&op=H4sIAAAAAAAEAKtWCkiszMlPTFGySkvMKU7VUfJNrHDOSCwqVrJSMjQwUNJRcszJyS93LSrKB4lBFTlllgSXFLnlF%2BUmlgAV5qTmpaQWgIi8EqAO%2F%2BSSVBT5xOLkzEylWgArpctbbQAAAA%3D%3D). If your module specifies the EXPLICIT TAGS the encoding  [won't match](https://asn1.io/PKI-inspector/default.aspx?databin=H4sIAAAAAAAEADPgXsYpzJSUKsxckJgJAHhHtiYNAAAA&schema=H4sIAAAAAAAEAHWPMQuDMBBG90D%2Bw406KNhCB6GD1SgBiZYolJYOEUUCNoKeS0v%2Fe62dhPqt78G7K5oRIWIxF7zgmZDALnnKQ15AESQSfP8IJ5ZwQclp0h1yI1GZWg11gDjoasJmXCTJziUTIYMXJTCvH1pl9FOh7o3qnMlodIx6zPbtcIdsRcsZioVl%2BfeIIIU3UELJlrYKSn5lYHmu6%2B32Nvzq%2F5fFG%2BHt1pLKB21QVV0j55dNC9YqaVPCRPQBYkBz5EgBAAA%3D&op=H4sIAAAAAAAEAKtWCkiszMlPTFGySkvMKU7VUfJNrHDOSCwqVrJSMjQwUNJRcszJyS93LSrKB4lBFTlllgSXFLnlF%2BUmlgAV5qTmpaQWgIi8EqAO%2F%2BSSVBT5xOLkzEylWgArpctbbQAAAA%3D%3D).

Comment: I understand the tags in the module definition. But I am struggling to understand the meaning of `IMPLICIT` in the sequence definition. For eg `organizational-unit-names [6] IMPLICIT OrganizationalUnitNames OPTIONAL` in the above example. Here what does that `IMPLICIT` indicate?

Comment: The **inline** IMPLICIT indicates the tag for this node, which can be different than the module tags mode (e.g. EXPLICIT TAGS).  To see the difference try encoding [with](https://t.ly/AOvo) and [without](https://t.ly/gc-Q) the inline IMPLICIT.